# cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data, url-routing

So I am using Ember 1.5.1 and Ember-data 1.0.0 beta7

I have the following routes

`App.Router.map ->
  @resource "items"
  @resource 'item', path: '/items/:id`

Item is fetched from server. These two routes work fine if I start on that route; weird thing happens when I start on a item page (/items/1), then I try to navigate to /items/ through a link with action handled by a function this.transitionToRoute("items") in ItemController. I got the following error:

Attempting transition to items ember.js?body=1:3524

Transition #2: items: calling beforeModel hook ember.js?body=1:3524

Transition #2: items: calling deserialize hook ember.js?body=1:3524

```
Error while loading route: Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
at Metamorph.checkRemoved (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:27009:15)
at Metamorph.html (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:26979:12)
at Object.DOMManager.empty (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:27974:16)
at Object.Ember.merge.empty (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:25139:21)
at Ember.CollectionView.Ember.ContainerView.extend.arrayWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:25962:25)
at Object.sendEvent (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:2600:14)
at Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:15317:11)
at superFunction [as _super] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:7726:16)
at RecordArray.extend.arrayContentWillChange (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7624:28)
at superWrapper [as arrayContentWillChange] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:1295:16)
```

Transition #2: items: transition was aborted

However, I click on the link again, and the transition succeeds. Then everything works fine no matter how I navigate between the two routes.

My initial guess is that not all records have been loaded, when I try to transition, but even though I start on /items/ and go to /items/1 then try to go back /items/, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, add following code in your action

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
    this.transitionToRoute("items");
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok just checked your stacktrace. The problem is not because of `transitionTORoute`. As this is metamorph issue, its little hard to debug directly. This may actually caused by wrong handlebars expressions.

- As pointed out in [this link](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1580), a simple issue can be using HTML comment blocks.

  {{! This comment will not be in the output }}
  < !-- This comment will be in the output -- >
- Manually manipulating the DOM. If you manually remove the script tags, then, well they won't be found.
- Malformed HTML. Let's say you left an open div, then the metamorph-##-end tag will get nested at a different level than the start tag.

I have extracted lot of these points from other questions which i think may help you